# Sample random variables conditional on their sum

Tags: random-variable, simulation, marginal-distribution, conditioning, jacobian

Let $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ be an iid sample of random variables with a known continuous distribution. I would like to simulate such a sample, *conditional on the value of its sum*, that is:
$$
X_1, \dots, X_n | \sum_{k=1}^n X_k = s
$$

If I was conditioning on, say $\sum_{k=1}^n X_k \in [s - \varepsilon, s+\varepsilon]$, then a solution would be to simulate an iid sample and discard the cases where the sum does not fall in $[s - \varepsilon, s+\varepsilon]$. It wouldn't be very efficient if $\varepsilon$ was small, but it would work. The problem here is that I'm trying to condition on a zero probability event, so that logic is not applicable.

I know there are cases ([normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/113209/7224), at least), where everything can be calculated analytically, but I seek a more general solution here.

Comment: Hint: $(X_1,\dots,X_n,\sum_{k=1}^n X_k)$ is a multivariate normal distribution, so you can use a [conditional distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you seek the conditional density of $(X_1,...,X_{n-1})$ given $$S=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$$ a change of variable from $$(X_1,...,X_{n})\sim\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i)$$ to $$\left(X_1,...,X_{n-1},S\right)\sim\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}f(x_i)\times f(s-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-1})$$ [with Jacobian equal to 1] shows that this conditional density is proportional to$$f(x_1)\cdots f(x_{n-1})\,f(s-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-1})$$

Therefore there exists a closed form expression for the conditional density and one can thus call a generic simulation method to simulate from it, like accept-reject, Gibbs sampling, or a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.

The resolution even extends to independent variables that are not identically distributed.

> **Note:** A [similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/113205/7224) was asked a while ago, but none of the
>   answers mentions this generic solution.

For instance, if $f$ is the N$(0,1)$ density and $n=4$, a Metropolis-within-Gibbs sampler for this problem would be of the form

```
T=1e3 #Gibbs steps
n=3 #n-1
s=3.1415 #imposed sum
x=matrix(rnorm(n),T,n)
for (t in 2:T){
  x[t,]=x[t-1,]
  for (i in 1:n){
   prop=rnorm(1,x[t-1,i],3)
   if (runif(1)<dnorm(prop)*
    dnorm(s-sum(x[t,-i])-prop)/
    dnorm(x[t-1,i])/dnorm(s-sum(x[t,]))) 
     x[t,i]=prop}}
```

Here is the outcome of the simulation of the three (first) components $x_1$ (brown), $x_2$ (red), and $x_3$ (yellow):

[image]

*[[reproduced from my blog]](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2018/04/19/fiducial-simulation/)* I recently came upon an unexpected property shown by [Lindqvist and Taraldsen (Biometrika, 2005)](https://folk.ntnu.no/bo/forskning/LindTarFestschrift.Revision.pdf) that to simulate a sample ${\bf y}$ conditional on the realisation of a sufficient statistic, $T({\bf y})=t⁰$, it is sufficient (!!!) to simulate the components of ${\bf y}$  as ${\bf y}=G({\bf u},θ)$, with ${\bf u}$ a random variable with fixed distribution, e.g., a $U(0,1)$, and to solve in $θ$ the fixed point equation $$T({\bf y})=T\circ G({\bf u},θ)=t⁰$$ 
assuming there exists a single solution to this equation.

To borrow a simple example from the authors, take an exponential sample ${\bf y}$ to be simulated given the sum statistic being fixed. As it is well-known, the conditional distribution of ${\bf y}$ is then a (rescaled) Beta and the proposed algorithm ends up being a standard Beta generator. For the method to work in general, $T({\bf y})$ must factorise through a function of the ${\bf u}$’s, a so-called *pivotal* condition. If this condition does not hold, it gets more complicated: the authors introduce a pseudo-prior distribution on the parameter $θ$ to make it independent from the ${\bf u}$’s conditional on $T({\bf y})=t⁰$. While the setting is necessarily one of exponential families and of sufficient conditioning statistics, I find it amazing that this property is not more well-known.

Comment: How could you modify these approach if you wanted to condition on S greater than a value, i.e., generate X_1,\ldots,X_n conditional on S > 10, for example? Would you need to first inverse transform sample from S|S >10?

Comment: @user21359: when conditioning on a positive probability event such as $S>10$, it is not possible to use a change of variable but one must constrain the original space for this event to happen. Check the keyword "cross-entropy" for efficient simulation in such cases.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any examples of something similar? A search of cross entropy most yielded information about estimating the probability of rare events rather than sampling from distributions.

Comment: I mean is there an example where someone uses cross entropy to estimate a similar problem kind of problem? I think I’m too new to this concept to construct it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth noting the normal case even though the questioner seeks a more general answer. Following the logic shown here  [How to generate two groups of $n$ random numbers in $U(0,1)$ such that sum of these two groups equal?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194335/how-to-generate-two-groups-of-n-random-numbers-in-u0-1-such-that-sum-of-th) leads to the result that for the normal case the conditional distributions are all normal.

So, for example, if we want to generate realizations of $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n$ that sum to $z$ where the $X_i$ are all identically normal, here is the resulting approach:

(1) Generate $X_1 \sim N \left({z \over n},{\frac{n-1}{n}} \sigma^2 \right)$

(2) Generate $X_2 \sim N \left({z-x_1 \over n-1},{\frac{n-2}{n-1}} \sigma^2 \right)$

For general $i,$

(3) Generate $X_i \sim N \left({z-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j \over {n-i+1}},{\frac{n-i}{n-i+1}} \sigma^2 \right)$

(4) Generate $X_{n-1} \sim \left({z-\sum_{j=1}^{n-2}x_j \over {2}},{\frac{\sigma^2}{2}} \right)$

(5) Let $X_n = z - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} x_j$